# Javascript Console Trouble

Tags: javascript

In general, in the JavaScript console, if it states:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'getElementByID'

what is the typical problem in your code? I'm new to JavaScript and in writing a program, this has repeatedly come up and I'm not sure how to fix the problem or what could even possibly be the problem.

Comment: user1248795, if indeed the problem was simply that you had `ID` instead of `Id` then you should accept either davin's answer or mine. If it was something else, then you should edit the question to make it clearer that there's a further problem.

Answer (score 8):

`getElementById` not `getElementByID`

Lower case `d`. JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

The typical problem is that you've typed `getElementByID` when you meant `getElementById`, probably. Alternatively, if that mistyping happened in transcribing the error message rather than in your original code :-), perhaps you did something that you thought would produce a DOM object but that actually produced `null` or `undefined` or something; there are lots of ways for that to happen.

Comment: Maybe the edit clarifies that a little - it's actually an `HTMLDocument`, so the casing is at fault.

Answer (score 0):

The right method name is `document.getElementById`.

Comment: Please don't be needlessly rude.

Comment: Excuse me for that. I didn't want to say anything rude. Just to set where the usual problems are hidden. Corrected.